# facebook and opengraph (ap id question)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am integrating a like button into one pf my pages, using the information [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

I want to use Open Graph Tags, but that requires supply of fb:admins or fb:app_id tag elements. The thing is that I cannot find any information on how to obtain these IDs.

The Id is that likes on the webpage appea on the wall of the facebook page (Note: NOT a user profile). Does anyone know which ID to use, and where to get the ID from?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your own user id to put into the fb:admins field by logging into facebook and then going to this url:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=2227470867|2.AQCPDqXNTW9FwNw9.3600.1311487200.0-29000387|0aZ4-swEk1RJo8PWMgzAqj-Daqs

The id field is your uid aka user id. If you don't have an app id, don't worry about it. You only need fb:admins OR fb:app_id. Not both.